# IllegalArgumentException error after added google jar

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-library

I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/protobuf/AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream;
```

and at the bottom of the Log,

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

after I added the 'libs' folder that includes jar files for google map/place that I'm trying to implement to an existing package.

[image]

I've done some research and found a solution which that

Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove all except the "Android X.Y"

but that's not in my case since I can't remove them from the list.(I can remove the Android Dependencies folder but i'm not sure if i should do that)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that you've got two jar files with duplicate classes. Try removing protobuf, if everything still compiles happily then hey presto you're in luck.

Otherwise, one workaround I found [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20956#c17) is:

> 1. Add the library project using project properties -> android - add library project.
> 2. Add the linked src files to your build path as well.
> 3. Build the project. You should see the class files  from you library project in the bin folder.
> 4. After that, REMOVE the linked src files from the library project in your application >project.
> 5. Run your application.
>
> If you clean the project, then repeat these steps from step 2.